# Create a collection from a call to an API with JSONP

Tags: api, backbone.js, jsonp

If this works fine:

```
$.getJSON('/* my URL */', function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Does this suppose to work also or am I doing something wrong:

```
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/* my URL */'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if you want to use **JSONP**:

```
var Data = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: "/* my URL */",

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options.timeout = 10000;
        options.dataType = "jsonp";
        return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx! I might have missed something but when I do in the view `var data = new Data();
data.fetch({
 success : function (res) {
  console.log("res " + res);
 }
});` I get nothing back, why is that? and no errors in the console

Comment: @IlyaD Hard to tell without looking more closely at your code. Try `data.fetch({error: function() { console.log(arguments); }});` to see if you get any errors.